# Magento 1.6 and products

Tags: magento

How can I add new products to Magento 1.6?
I have tried this:-

```
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    $product->setWebsiteIds(array('1'));
    $product->setAttributeSetId(4);

    $product->setType('Simple');
    $product->setName("test");
    $product->setDescription('[description]');
    $product->setShortDescription('[short_description]');
    $product->setPrice($arg_data['price']);
    $product->setWeight($arg_data['weight']);
    $product->setStatus(1);
    $product->setTaxClassId(2);
    $product->setCategoryIds($arg_data['category_ids']);
    $product->setVisibility(4);

    $product->save();
```

Comment: product appear , but they didn't have a category

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For categories you have to declare the ids in an array, like this:

```
$product->setCategoryIds( array( $arg_data['category_ids'] ) );
```

Multiple categories would be like:

```
$product->setCategoryIds( array( 1, 5, 23, 98 ) );
```